# Why do I get two different point array renders on laptop, integrated and 1050Ti, python opengl code?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl

I currently use Asus TUF FX505G that has both integrated and 1050Ti graphic unit. While trying to render array of points to screen, I found out that I would get two different results depeding on which GPU is in use. On 1050Ti the code works not intended. Python version 3.10.8
[image: Incorrect behavior on 1050Ti, power plugged in]
[image: Correct behaviour while using motherboard gpu, power unplugged]

Main.py

```
import glfw
import Shader
from OpenGL.GL import *
from Math_3d import Vector3f


class Window:
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int, title: str):
        # Exit keyboard flag
        self.exitNow = False

        # Vertex Buffer Object
        # Create point vertex data
        self.v3f = Vector3f.data

        if not glfw.init():
            raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized")

        # OpenGL 4.0 version for shader subroutines and Dynamically uniform expression support
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

        self._win = glfw.create_window(width, height, title, None, None)

        if not self._win:
            glfw.terminate()
            raise Exception("glfw window can not be created")

        glfw.set_window_pos(self._win, 400, 200)
        glfw.make_context_current(self._win)
        # Enable key events
        # glfw.set_input_mode(self._win, glfw.STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE)
        # Enable key event callback from keyboard
        # glfw.set_key_callback(self._win, self.onKeyboard)
        self.program = glCreateProgram()
        self.buffer = glGenBuffers(1)

    def initialize(self):
        # Request program and shader slots from the GPU

        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        # Set shader sources
        glShaderSource(vertex, Shader.vertex_code)
        glShaderSource(fragment, Shader.fragment_code)
        # Compile shaders and check that they have compiled
        glCompileShader(vertex)
        glCompileShader(fragment)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_shader = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex)
            print(report_shader)
            raise RuntimeError("Vertex shader compilation error")

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_frag = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment)
            print(report_frag)
            raise RuntimeError("Fragment shader compilation error")

        # Link shaders to program
        glAttachShader(self.program, vertex)
        glAttachShader(self.program, fragment)
        glLinkProgram(self.program)

        if not glGetProgramiv(self.program, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            print(glGetProgramInfoLog(self.program))
            raise RuntimeError('Linking error')
        # Get rid of shaders
        glDetachShader(self.program, vertex)
        glDetachShader(self.program, fragment)
        # Make default program to run
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        # Request a buffer slot from GPU
        # buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        # Make this buffer the default one
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffer)
        # Vertex Array Buffer
        vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)

        loc = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, 'position')
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, self.v3f.itemsize, GL_FLOAT, False, self.v3f.data.strides[0], None)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.v3f.data.nbytes, self.v3f.data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

    def renderscene(self):
        while not glfw.window_should_close(self._win) and not self.exitNow:
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            glPointSize(30)
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, self.v3f.itemsize)

            glfw.swap_buffers(self._win)
            # Do not refresh screen before receiving event
            glfw.wait_events()
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glUseProgram(0)
        glfw.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window(1024, 768, "GLFW Window - Rotate glPoints")
    win.initialize()  # Create and initialize shaders and initialize Vertex Buffer Object
    win.renderscene()  # Swap buffer and render scene
```

Shader.py

```
vertex_code = """
    attribute vec3 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    }   
    """

fragment_code = """
    void main() 
    { 
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0); 
    }
    """
```

Math_3d.py

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)


class Vector3f:
    data = np.array([[0.5, 0.5, 0],
                    [-0.5, 0.5, 0],
                    [-0.5, -0.5, 0],
                    [0.5, -0.5, 0]], dtype=np.float32)

    def Rotate(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vec3 = Vector3f
    print(vec3.data)
    print("Item size: ", vec3.data.itemsize)
    print("Strides: ", vec3.data.strides[0])
    print("Bytes:", vec3.data.nbytes)
```

Ran the code while using both gpus. There should be no apparent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

> ```py
> glVertexAttribPointer(loc, self.v3f.itemsize, GL_FLOAT, False, self.v3f.data.strides[0], None)
> ```

The 2nd argument of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the number of components of the attribute (x, y, z), which is 3. However, `itemsize` is the number of bytes of an item, which is 4 for an item of type `float`.

Correct is:

```py
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, self.v3f.data.strides[0], None)
```